# C++ member variable with same name as in parent works without full qualification (as long as it is expansive?)

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++14, member

I have read a couple questions dealing with parent and child classes having member variables with the same name, and the accepted approach seems to be to just fully qualify the required variable needed (e.g. in the body of a method in the child class) `Parent::foo` or `Child::foo` and everything should work.

Nevertheless, I am curious about the following example I came across with. I am trying to prepare a hierarchy of classes, each of them representing some gadget requiring a specific configuration. The configuration I want to pass in a dedicated `struct`.

Because I will have different gadget types of the same family, I have a parent gadget (with virtual methods and methods common to all specific types of gadgets) with a parent config (holding all config parameters needed for all gadget types). Further than that, I will have child gadget classes overriding the parent virtual methods and also using parent methods needed for any gadget type. These child gadgets require more specific configuration parameters which are not needed for other specific (cousin) gadget types, and which are, therefore, beyond the scope of the parent, generic gadget.

I learned that I can call that configuration `config` both in parent and child, and accessing member variables of that config (those configs) from a method in the child class works fine without full qualification. Here is a toy example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct ConfigBase
{
    float x;
    explicit ConfigBase(float x_): x(x_) {}
};


struct ConfigDerived: public ConfigBase
{
    float y;
    explicit ConfigDerived(float x_, float y_): ConfigBase(x_), y(y_) {}
};


class ObjectBase
{
public:
    ConfigBase config;
    explicit ObjectBase(ConfigBase config_): config(config_) {}
};


class ObjectDerived: public ObjectBase
{
public:
    static ConfigBase castToParentConfig(const ConfigDerived& config)
    {
        ConfigBase parentConfig = config;  // Here I am slicing away some member variables of my ConfigDerived instance
        return config;
    };

    void printMemberVars()
    {
        std::cout << "x: " <<config.x << std::endl;
        std::cout << "y: " <<config.y << std::endl;
    }

    ConfigDerived config;
    explicit ObjectDerived(ConfigDerived config_): ObjectBase(castToParentConfig(config_)), config(config_) {}
};


int main() {

    ConfigDerived config(1.f, 2.f);
    ObjectDerived foo(config);
    foo.printMemberVars();

    return 0;
}
```

The above executable works just fine:

```
x: 1
y: 2

Process finished with exit code 0
```

There are only three options I can think of why this is working:

1. The compiler has constructed on purpose an overarching `config` that holds in one `struct` all the member variables of child an parent, so that I can access all config members as if there was only one `config`.
2. It is the accidental result of me initializing "part of a child member variable", slicing away the initialized part, and passing the trimmed version upstream for having the parent initialize the remaining part of the variable under the same name.
3. C++ has some kind of hard-coded member resolution order. In case I look for an attribute of a member variable with the same name in parent and child, it first tries to find it in the parent, and if it fails, in the child (or the other way around)

Originally I was expecting `config.x` to not be accessible at all, due to the definition of the member variable with the same name in the child class and the lack of full qualification when accessing it. That expectation was clearly not reasonable.

Can someone explain me what is happening here? Is this considered bad style or a bad use of this C++ capability?

Comment: What member variable with the same name in the child class? The only `ConfigDerived::x` I can see is the one it inherits from `ConfigBase`.

Comment: you are confusing too many things at once. I suggest you to start with a simpler example. Look at only `ConfigBase` and `ConfigDerived` alone. In `ConfigDerived` there are members `x` and `y`.

Comment: `ObjectDerived` indeed has two members `config`, but because both have a `x` member, your line of reasoning is a little ... confused

Comment: @NathanPierson I meant the variable `config` which appears both in `ObjectBase` and `ObjectDerived`

Comment: When you use `config` in `ObjectDerived`, you're using its `ConfigDerived` member. This object is completely unrelated to the `ConfigBase` member of the same name in `ObjectBase`.

Comment: "Originally I was expecting config.x to not be accessible at all," this is wrong expectations. I don't quite see where you went off, but it is not clear why you think it should not be accessible. Any `config` in your code has a member `x` that is `public`

Comment: `ObjectDerived::config` isn't just "the non-`ConfigBase` portions of a `ConfigDerived`", it's an entire `ConfigDerived`. Since `ConfigDerived::x` exists, `foo.config.x` is perfectly valid. This does mean that you're storing some duplicate information, because foo's shadowed `ConfigBase` named `config` is a separate object from its `ConfigDerived` named `config`.

Comment: @NathanPierson Yes i think you totally caught the mistake in my understanding, the logic conclusion of which is, of course, that I am storing duplicated information. Thanks all for the help. I understand.

Comment: "a couple questions dealing with parent and child classes having member variables with the same name" Here's the answer to all of these questions. **Don't**.

Comment: If you think that perhaps the base and derived `config.x` are the same object ... why not just mutate one and then print them both? Or print their addresses? You can interrogate this stuff directly to see what is actually happening.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.  Of course I wouldn't have wanted to do that, but rather give them different names. I was just confused when it did work in this state.

Answer (score 1):

> *Originally I was expecting config.x to not be accessible at all, …*

I'm not sure why you thought this. The `ObjectDerived` class has a `ConfigDerived` member and that `ConfigDerived` structure is derived from `ConfigBase` – so it has both `y` (its 'own') and `x` (inherited from the base) elements. **Note:** The `x` member is inherited from the base structure as part of the (separate) `config` data member; it *does not* inherit `x` from the base class `config` structure, which is a separate object and hidden from the derived class.

> *Is this considered bad style or a bad use of this C++ capability?*

Ultimately, that's a matter of opinion. However, I would say that it *is* poor coding style that can lead to unexpected and confusing results (as you have noted). The two compilers I tested your code on agree with me.

The MSVC compiler in Visual Studio 2019 gives the following warning (twice – once on each line of your `castToParentConfig` function:

> warning C26437: Do not slice (es.63).

The clang-cl compiler (also in VS-2019) gives different warnings related to the same issue:

> warning : non-static data member 'config' of 'ObjectDerived' shadows
> member inherited from type 'ObjectBase' [-Wshadow-field]
> warning : parameter 'config' shadows member inherited from type 'ObjectBase'
> [-Wshadow-field]

In the fairly simple code you have posted, these "shadowing" and "slicing" issues are relatively innocuous; however, in more general cases, hiding a data member of a base class in a derived class will likely cause more serious issues, particularly when the member types are not so closely related.

Here is a summary of [Microsoft's policy on slicing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c26437?view=msvc-160):

> Slicing is allowed by compiler and can be viewed as a special case of
> dangerous implicit cast. Even if it is done intentionally and doesn’t
> lead to immediate issues, it is still highly discouraged since it
> makes code rather unmaintainable by forcing additional requirements on
> related data types. This is especially true if types are polymorphic
> or involve resource management.

Comment: As far I have understood from above answers this part of your answer  "so it has both y (its 'own') and x (inherited from the base) elements." does not fit, as the `x` member variable of the `ConfigDerived` is also its own. Otherwise I should NOT be able to access it if I have overwritten it with another object with the same name `config`. It works because it just happens that the `ConfigDerived` also happens to have an `x` member variable, which by chance also happens to hold the same value as `ConfigBase.x`. Am I wrong?

Comment: @mosegui Yeah - I'll need to clarify that. There are two separate objects called `config` in the derived class but one is hidden by the other. What I meant was that the derived structure in the derived class inherits its `x` member from the *definition* of the base structure.

Answer (score 0):

Structs have public access by default so in your current implementation they will be public and available without need for qualification.

https://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/